# How do I consistently set up the environment when unit testing in dart?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

Is there a way to have setup/teardown code automagically run before/after each test?
Something similar in effect to the @Before annotation available with jUnit.

Comment: Like [this?](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/new-setupteardown-in-unit-test-library.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it but only in group test :

```
group('foo', () {
  setUp(() {...});
  tearDown(() {...});
  test(description, () {...});
  ...
});
```

For more information, read this [news](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/new-setupteardown-in-unit-test-library.html).